# playgameservices GameHelper - any way to not use a modal progress dialog during signins?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm using the GameHelper class provided by google for a... game:

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/BaseGameUtils/src/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java

Every time onStart() is called, the implementation tries to reconnect, popping up a modal progress window. When onStop() is called, the connections are closed.

This means that whenever the user starts the app, or navigates to another activity and returns to our main activity, they'll get a modal progress dialog popping up.

Has anyone found a way to do this more elegantly using the code provided by google? I'm thinking it'd be good enough to just render a small message to the side like "signing you in..." instead of blocking the user until signin is complete. It'd also be nice to have this library work at the application level rather than the activity level - now you have to stuff your whole app into an activity if you don't want the onStop() method severing the connection.

Thanks

------------------Update-----------------

I'm just extending from BaseGameActivity, which calls through to GameHelper. This is what onStop() looks like inside GameHelper.java:

```
/** Call this method from your Activity's onStop(). */
public void onStop() {
    debugLog("onStop: disconnecting clients.");

    // disconnect the clients -- this is very important (prevents resource
    // leaks!)
    killConnections(CLIENT_ALL);

    ...
```

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/BaseGameUtils/src/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java#L313

so when the corresponding call to onStart() is made from my activity (either resuming an activity, or starting the app again), it has to go through the connection process again:

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/BaseGameUtils/src/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java#L290

which eventually pops up the progress dialog. This only happens if you had previously signed in of course.

Nobody else is seeing that? The progress dialog only pops up for a split second before disappearing. Here's my activity:

```
public class ActivityMain extends BaseGameActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        enableDebugLog(true, "###");

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        Log.e("###", "onSignInSucceeded()…");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        Log.e("###", "onSignInSucceeded()…");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code, on my game it doesn't show this modal screen everytime...

Answer (score 0):

You can first, without breaking the signin-flow, remove any occurrence related to ProgressDialog or simply shortcircuit the **showProgressDialog** method in *GameHelper.java*.

Then in your activity, you can handle yourself "what to do/what to show" if you mainly override **beginUserInitiatedSignIn**, **onSignInFailed** and **onSignInSucceeded**.